# Windows Universal App Continuous Dictation Without Network

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, uwp, cortana

Following the samples provided here: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples provides a great overview of some of the capabilities for UWP apps.  But, the speech example seems to require an active connection to the internet.  Does anyone know if this capability is possible on a disconnected corporate network?

Thanks, JRF

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Examples 1, 2, 5, 6 and 9 work Offline since they don't use the predefined SRGS scenarios. Look in the Folder: SRGS to see the SRGS.

You will have to write your own speech recognition grammar following the [SRGS Version 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/).

[How to define custom recognition constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792132.aspx/)

Comment: This isn't quite correct, the SRGS grammars aren't the only ones that will function without an active connection. The ListGrammar scenarios will also work just fine. The only scenarios that require a connection in the samples are 3, 4 and 7 (the dictation scenarios)

Comment: Sir, You are correct except for scenario 7 which requires network connectivity.  Unplugging the network cable from my system causes a "Continuous Recognition Completed:  Network Failure" error.

Comment: What? I said 7 needs a network connection in my comment, since it's a dictation scenario. I probably should have been more clear. Scenario 8 should also work without a network connection, as local grammars do not require the dictation service to work, but you didn't include that in your list above on this answer. I just double-checked that here on a system with networking disabled.